# Delete query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, liquibase, delete-row

can someone please help to put the below query in the liquibase syntax:

```
delete  from test_table t1
where exists (select emails from test_table t2
where t2.emails=t1.emails
and t2.rowid< t1.rowid);

----------
```

Answer (score 1):

I think only way to achieve this is put it inside a sql tag

```
   <sql >delete  from test_table t1
where exists (select emails from test_table t2
where t2.emails=t1.emails
and t2.rowid< t1.rowid)
</sql>
```